# How to get a DateTime from invoke-sqlcmd on powershell?

Tags: sql-server-2008, powershell

I have the following query to a sql server database from powershell 2.0

```
$fec_fin = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "select date From table where date >= GetDate() ORDER BY date"
```

Here `$fec_fin` is a variable of the type `DataRow`, and I need it to be a `DateTime` type.

Comment: How many rows will you get back? And are you *certain* that the answer will always be the same?

Comment: What does the data look like when you get it returned?

Answer (score 0):

If the column is a datetime try :

```
$fec_fin.date
```

otherwise, try

```
[Datetime]$fec_fin.date
```